# css when hover show multiple color around div using css or javascript

Tags: css

I use css to show colors around div when hover but I want to make it more than one color [live demo](https://js-demo.com/index.php?ref=387dde5d75c2) I want it to be multiple colors instead of one

```
.container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.container a{
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 20px;
}
.container a::before,
.container a::after
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    background: rgb(26, 214, 58);
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.container a:hover:before
{
    inset: -3px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having a background set as a single RGB color you can set it as a background-image with multi colors introduced through a gradient.

This snippet uses a linear-gradient (which gives a sort of image type) with just 3 colors but you can have more and you can adjust how much of each you get and whether the changes go from top to bottom or left to right - see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Using_CSS_gradients) documentation for the various options.

The result here is:

[image]

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Zilla+Slab:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Zilla Slab', serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #0e1538;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.container a {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 20px;
}

.container a::before,
.container a::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background: rgb(26, 214, 58);
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, green, blue);
  /* ADDED */
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.container a:hover:before {
  inset: -3px;
}

.container a span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #0e1538;
  z-index: 10;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">
    <span>Hover Me</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Zilla+Slab:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap');
body {
  background-color: #0e1538;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}    
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
}   
.btn {
  font-family: 'Zilla Slab', serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #0e1538;
  width: 190px;
  height: 50px;
}
.center-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.btn-wrapper:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #00C0FF 0%, #FFCF00 49%, #FC4F4F 100%);
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="btn-wrapper center-flex">
  <a href=#><div class="btn center-flex">Hover Me</div></a>
</div>
</body>
```